# Saving R timevis timeline in html webpage

Tags: html, r, widget, save, timeline.js

I'm sure I'm missing a basic issue but I'm not currently able to find my way out of this problem.

Is there a way to save a simple (not Shiny) Timevis timeline in html webpage from the code?
I've successfully tried by using RStudio export button but I would like to include the function in the code.

`htmlwidgets::saveWidget()` doesn't work properly as the webpage is incomplete e.g. zoom buttons are missing (see [incomplete webpage print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF8U6.jpg)) even with a minimal code:

```
 myTimeline<-timevis(
         data.frame(id = 1:2,
                    content = c("one", "two"),
                    start = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-12"))
     )
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(myTimeLine,"myTimeLine.html")
```

Thank in advance for any help and advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/issues/275) on github about this.
The workaround is to use `selfcontained = FALSE`:

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(myTimeline, "myTimeLine.html", selfcontained = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a selfcontained version (e.g. because you want to offer this htmlwidget via `plumber`), the issue is the lack of zoom buttons.

If you modify the output HTML content to re-include the zoom buttons properly, everything works fine.